# is the below static utility method Threadsafe

Tags: java, multithreading

I am writing a static utility method.I know methods isEmpty() , isNew()  are threadsafe..In getTotal(...)method I am using StringBuilder as parameter alomg with String and int.StringBuilder is mutable. Is getTotal() threadsafe.If so explain why it is even though StringBuilder is mutable . 
  But I am not sure if getCharge() is thread safe bcz its invoking the method  getTotal().
Can someone tell if it is threadsafe or not

```
public class NewStringUtils {

    public static boolean  isEmpty(String s){
        return (s == null || s.trim().length()==0);
    }

    public static boolean isNew(String code){
        return( "1009".equals(code) || "1008".equals(code) );
    }
    //StringBuilder is  mutable  -- is the below method threadsafe 
    public static int getTotal(StringBuilder sb,String oldCode ,int a, int b){
        //Is it Threadsafe or not .If so  just bcz every thread invoking this method will have its own copy and other threads can't see its value ?? 
        int k =0;
        if("1011".equals(oldCode) && "1021".equals(sb.toString()) {
            k = a+b;
        }
        return k;
    }
    // is the below method threadsafe 
    public static  int getCharge(String code,String oldCode,int charge1,int charge2){
        int total =0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("1021");
        if(!NewStringUtils.isEmpty(code)){

            if(NewStringUtils.isNew(code)){
                //here invoking a static method which has StringBuilder(Mutable) as a         parameter
                total  = NewStringUtils.getTotal(sb,oldCode,charge1,charge2);
            }
        }

        return total;
     }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect it is not thread safe?

Answer (score 7):

It is. You are not using any fields / variables that are not method scoped and all the parameters to the methods are immutable, so therefore it is thread-safe.

The only thread-safety risk in a method that does not use any non-method scoped variables is if the parameters are mutable and therefore could be modified by another thread. Since primitives and `String` are immutable, you are good.

EDIT: Posted comment:

> How about this: if a method (static or otherwise) uses only
>   method-scoped variables, has only immutable parameters and only
>   invokes other thread-safe methods then it must be thread-safe

Comment: String is immutable but int is mutable right.so do you still think its threadsafe

Comment: primitives are not mutable (there is not such thing as `myInt.set(..)`). Also, my definition primitives are passed to methods as by value (as it impossible to have a reference to a primitive).

Comment: so according to you if i have a mutable object like StringBuffer as a parameter  in getTotal() it becomes non threadsafe public static int getTotal(StringBuffer sb, String oldCode ,int a, int b){
        int k =0;
        if("1011".equals(oldCode)) {
            k = a+b;
        }
        return k;
    }

Comment: correct. For example if `getCharge` took a `StringBuffer` then the value of the parameter could change between the calls to `isEmpty` and `isNew`

Comment: ok .If static method is not using state information  then  primitives and immutable objects as parameters in a static method   is always threadsafe. Problem arises if I use immutable objects as parameters

Comment: How about this: if a method (static or otherwise) uses only method-scoped variables, has only immutable parameters and only invokes other thread-safe methods then it must be thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

Your static methods don't have any state between calls. All state passed by parameter...so its thread safe.

Answer (score 2):

All the variables are local variables and there are no shared variables between the threads (static variables since it's static method), and the passed references are either primitives or insances of an immutable class. Hence, it's thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. `ints` are passed by value. And the `Strings` are parameters of the method. You're not using any field from outside the method.

**EDIT**

If you want to use `StringBuilder` instead of `String`, you'll need to synchronize on the `StringBuilder` object.

```
public someMethod(StringBuilder sb, ...) {
    synchronized(sb) {

        //this will make sb thread safe.
        //but do this everywhere you access this StringBuilder Object.

    }
}
```

Comment: so what if i change method def to public static int getTotal(StringBuffer sb, String oldCode ,int a, int b){

Since StringBuffer is mutable , is it still going to be threadsafe

public static int getTotal(StringBuffer sb, String oldCode ,int a, int b){
        int k =0;
         if(sb!=null && NewStringUtils.isEmpty(sb.toString)){
               if("1020".equals(sb.toString){
         if("1011".equals(oldCode)) {
             k = a+b;
         }
                }
          }
        return k;
}

Comment: Then, no. You'll need to synchronize on the StringBuffer object.

Comment: Thanks.SO I  have to acquire class level lock(this being a static method) in getTotal(StringBuffer sb,String code,int ch1,int ch2) method to make it threadsafe .Inside the method  synchronized(this.class){  //then make changes on string buffer }

Comment: No. You don't want to synchroinze on the class, but in the StringBuffer object. Where you use this StringBuffer, you'll need a synchronized block.

Comment: sorry i did not get it.I think i should get class level  synchronized(NewUtils.class){   and act on StringBuffer  } .correct me i am wrong

Comment: or should I declare static member variable like private static Object obj and synchronzie(ob){ //act on StringBuffer or any immutable object }

Comment: I Agree that i should  get object level lock  if the someMethod(StringBuilder sb , ...) is 
an instance method.
but what if this someMethod(StringBuilder sb, ...) is  static , then I should get class level lock.Is that right

Comment: It won't be necessary. None of the class fields are used in this case.

Comment: even though StringBuilder is  not a  class feild , since StringBuilder is mutable    and this method being a static method do i need to obtain class level lock

Comment: The variable scope is only inside the method. It is not shared even if the same method is called more than once concurrently.